# Magento 2 - Use knockoutjs and html instead of phtml

Tags: layout, knockoutjs, phtml, html, component

How can I use html and knockoutjs on a custom site which is accessible from a custom controller?

For example my controller route is **threepartment/vault/index**

If I go to:

`www.example.com/threepartment/vault/index`

then my **phtml** template is getting loaded.

**Template:** `app/code/Threepartment/Debitpayment/view/frontend/templates/vault/index.phtml`

```
test
```

**Layout:**  `app/code/Threepartment/Debitpayment/view/frontend/layout/threepartment_vault_index.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>

    <head>
        <title>Bankkonto Daten</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <referenceContainer name="content">
          <block name="vault.index"
                class="Threepartment\Debitpayment\Block\Vault\Index"
                template="Threepartment_Debitpayment::vault/index.phtml"
                cacheable="false"
          />
      </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

---

**Question:** How can I solve it with knockoutjs and a html file instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://www.magedelight.com/resources/how-to-use-knockout-js-in-magento-2/).

In my example I use **Threepartment_Debitpayment** as module

## Layout

First you need to create a normal layout where you create a block with a `phtml` template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
                   name="knockoutexe"
                   template="Threepartment_Debitpayment::index_ko.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

## Phtml Template

app/code/Threepartment/Debitpayment/view/frontend/templates/vault/index_ko.phtml

```
<div id="md-knockout-example" data-bind="scope:'td-ko-example'">
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<script>
    window.foo = 'bar';
</script>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "td-ko-example": {
                    "component": "Threepartment_Debitpayment/js/component"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</div>
```

## Component

app/code/Threepartment/Debitpayment/view/frontend/web/js/component.js

```
define(
['jquery', 'uiComponent', 'ko']
,function ($, Component, ko) {
    'use strict';
        return Component.extend({

        defaults: {
            template: 'Threepartment_Debitpayment/test'
        },

        initialize: function () {
            console.log(window.foo);
            this._super();
        }
    });
});
```

## HTML Template

app/code/Threepartment/Debitpayment/view/frontend/web/template/test.html

```
<div class="component-class">
    <div data-bind="text: 'Knockout Works Successfully'"></div>
</div>
```